# Setting gensim wordVectors init_sim property as True error - ValueError: output array is read-only

Tags: nlp, gensim, word-embedding

Below is the code, I am executing. The error occurs on the 3rd line (`vectors.init_sims(True)`)

```
fname = get_tmpfile(path_to_embedding_file)
vectors = KeyedVectors.load(fname, mmap='r')

vectors.init_sims(True)
```

This is the error stack-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_pair_histograms.py", line 82, in <module>
    vectors.init_sims(True) # normalize the vectors (!), so we can use the dot product as similarity measure
  File "C:\users\janki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1354, in init_sims
    self.vectors_norm = _l2_norm(self.vectors, replace=replace)
  File "C:\users\janki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 2374, in _l2_norm
    m /= dist
ValueError: output array is read-only
```

Is this a known issue? Can someone provide a solution or workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

By using the optional, non-default `mmap='r'` parameter when you loaded the `KeyedVectors`, you specifically requested an instance that was backed by a read-only (`'r'`) view of a disk file that won't be changed by that view.

Then, by using `True` as an optional, non-default argument to the `.init_sims(replace=True)` call, you've requested that a precalculation of unit-normed vectors that *replaces* the original values. You can't overwrite the values in a read-only view, hence the error.

Depending on what you really want to do, which isn't clear, do at least one of:

- leave out the `mmap` argument entirely: you'll get a regular in-memory `KeyedVectors` that you can modify any way you'd like, while it's in memory, and could then choose to save later. (but, you may *not* want to save a unit-normed version when you've already got a raw non-normed set – you can always unit-normalize the raw vectors, but you can't go the other way.)
- leave out the `True` to `.init_sims()`: that step will then create a 2nd array with the unit-normed values, not attempting to write into the raw array
- change the `mmap` argument to allow reading & writing - you probably don't want to do this.